# Is there ready to use solution using grunt orgulp or webpack to optimize html, css, js, image resources for page speed?

Tags: gruntjs, gulp, webpack, minify

I have written a static site and want to use github-pages to host it.

The source code is ready, it involves html page, css files, js files, images ... I have linked the resource in the html page.

But the problem is the page loading speed is rather slow, it takes a lot of time loading all the above resources.

So I want to optimize the resources in my page. I know there're small pieces of npm modules doing different jobs for different resources. But it costs me ages to go through all the document for these modules and set up a build job myself.

So I'm wondering if there're already some ready to use solution which I can immediately adopt, my requirements is simple:

1. minify images, and convert image to base64 and input them in html page
2. minify js, and concat them all together
3. minify css, and concat them
4. minify html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every project has its own requirements, its own folder structure, etc, so you'll want something customized for your setup. But this is easy to set up once you know how. For example you'll be able to do this with Gulp after a little study. Read https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/, then use [`gulp-imagemin`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin) [`gulp-clean-css`](https://github.com/scniro/gulp-clean-css), [`gulp-concat`](https://github.com/contra/gulp-concat), [`gulp-uglify`](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify), [`gulp-htmlmin`](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/gulp-htmlmin), and probably [`gulp-rename`](https://github.com/hparra/gulp-rename)

Comment: even though every project has its own project structure. The overall requirements are the same: reduce the file size and minimum the request times. So I want to find a common guide line, what are the things need to be done and the sequence to do them. thanks for your answer. I'm looking into that.

Comment: I just want to say, the tutorial you linked is awesome!! It solves all my problems. Thanks a ton!!!